# What is a pure functional version of this Jax function?

Tags: lambda, iterator, closures, jax

I am writing a simple classifier in an attempt to come to grips with Jax. I want to normalize the data (it's the Iris dataset from sklearn) and my little function works, but from what I've read in the Jax the Sharp Bits documentation, I should avoid using lambda functions and iterating over vectors. I am not versed in functional programming, and I am curious if there's a better, more Jax idomatic way to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp 
from jax import jit, vmap 
# lots of imports ... 

iris = load_it('data', 'iris.pkl')

def normalize(data): 
    return jnp.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x/jnp.linalg.norm(x), 1, data) 

# TODO: use a functional style, maybe use partial
# and get rid of the lambda ...

tic = time.perf_counter() 
iris_data_normal = normalize(iris.data) 
toc = time.perf_counter() 
print(f"It took jax {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds.")
```

When I run this I get: `It took jax 0.0677 seconds.` Any guidance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach looks fine to me: it is pure (the function has no side-effects) and in JAX `apply_along_axis` is [implemented in terms of `vmap`](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/jax-v0.4.6/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py#L2945-L2953), so there's no problem in terms of computational efficiency.

If you wanted to write a similar function using direct array operations, you could equivalently do something like this:

```py
def normalize(data):
  return data / jnp.linalg.norm(data, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome. And it's faster.